# Adding number-defined random points within polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point

I'm trying to add points within polygons using the random points tools (I'm on qgis 2.18.2). What I want to achieve --I don't know if it's possible-- is populate these polygons with a defined number of points, as in a column of the shapefile.

Specifically, it's a city map by blocks and a shapefile column has the number of shops in that block. Random points-fixed doesn't allow column selection, while random points-variable allows it, but generates a really random number of points. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can't reproduce. `Random points inside polygons (variable)` works for me exactly like you described (QGIS 2.18.11) - generates the number of points in polygon according to selected attribute. Ensure that you chose right layer, attribute, and sampling strategy -  *Points count*.

Comment: I think I've found the problem. It's a conflict with decimal delimiter. Spanish uses comma (,) so actual numbers have been multiplied by 1000 during the conversion to shp. Too many points inside polygons made me think it was a random number, related to the original in some way, but random. Thanks Oto